# QFileDialog How to set filename to the text field and use QFileDialog separately with few textfields

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to write GUI for a program that must perform some actions with given files. Its logic will be:

1) Program starts with one text field and one button created.

2) If I click on button, I can choose some `.exe` file. If the file is choosen, its path is set to the textfield that is logicaly linked with first my button.

3) If the file is choosen on previous step, a new pair of text field and button linked to it is created. The size of main window must change dynamically when a new pair is added.

How can I set the path to the file to current textfield?
I need a possibility to edit data in any text field. How to organize interface so that I could separately use `QFileDialog` with any pair of textfield and button.

I cant figure out how to use signals/slots in this case.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void makeInterface();

private slots:
    void openFile();
};

#endif


#include <QString>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    makeInterface();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}

void MainWindow::openFile()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
            this,
            tr("OpenFile"),
            QDir::currentPath(),
            tr("Executable Files (*.exe)"));
    if (!fileName.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << fileName;
    }
}

void MainWindow::makeInterface()
{
    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;

    QLineEdit   *fldFilePath = new QLineEdit;
    QPushButton *btnOpenFile = new QPushButton("*.exe");
    connect(btnOpenFile, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(openFile()));

    mainLayout->addWidget(fldFilePath, 0, 0);
    mainLayout->addWidget(btnOpenFile, 0, 1);

    QPushButton *btnBuild = new QPushButton("Build");

    mainLayout->addWidget(btnBuild, 5, 0);

    setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```

Comment: You can get the value of your text field with `fldFilePath->text()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html) for this.

Your code may looks like this:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSignalMapper>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void makeInterface();

private slots:
    void openFile(QWidget* widget);

private:
    QSignalMapper _mapper;
};

#endif


#include <QString>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    connect(&_mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(openFile(QWidget*)));

    makeInterface();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}

void MainWindow::openFile(QWidget* widget)
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
            this,
            tr("OpenFile"),
            QDir::currentPath(),
            tr("Executable Files (*.exe)"));
    if (!fileName.isNull())
    {
        static_cast<QLineEdit*>(widget)->setText(fileName);
    }
}

void MainWindow::makeInterface()
{
    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;

    QLineEdit   *fldFilePath = new QLineEdit;
    QPushButton *btnOpenFile = new QPushButton("*.exe");
    connect(btnOpenFile, SIGNAL(clicked()), &_mapper, SLOT(map()));
    _mapper.setMapping(btnOpenFile, fldFilePath);

    mainLayout->addWidget(fldFilePath, 0, 0);
    mainLayout->addWidget(btnOpenFile, 0, 1);

    QPushButton *btnBuild = new QPushButton("Build");

    mainLayout->addWidget(btnBuild, 5, 0);

    setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```